# Mysql query interception before executing in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, redis

Recently I developed a full automated DB cache solution - mysql+redis. Based on sql queries it builds cache, reset and updates itself all without manual cache managing. It's also apply on multiple joins, inserts, deletes and updates. It works fantastic on production in my previous project writen on PHP from the scratch without framework.

I would like to make this plugin compatible with Laravel.
The problem is to find the best solution of injection, so it will be possible to intercept sql queries and return cache instead of sql execution.

The solution must be one universal. It must intercept, handle and return cached result for all the SQL not mater ORM or DB.

Will be glad to share final solution in open source once done.

Any ideas?